# Jquery UI script not loading

Tags: javascript

I have a beginner's problem with jquery UI script not loading. Basically I am trying to make some checkboxes as buttons but this is not working when I declared jquery UI script like this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="check" /><label for="check">Toggle</label>

<div id="format">
  <input type="checkbox" id="check1" /><label for="check1">B</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check2" /><label for="check2">I</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check3" /><label for="check3">U</label>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ftraian/cu8mS

Comment: In jsfiddle you're not really supposed to add `<script>` elements within the html pane as well as including others in the _Frameworks & Extensions_ options - you were mixing the two. If you select jquery-ui from the _Frameworks & Extensions_ options at the left it works: http://jsfiddle.net/cu8mS/2/ In a real webpage include both jquery and jquery ui as per Tieson T.'s answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See your modified Fiddle, I added jQuery and jQuery ui css http://jsfiddle.net/cu8mS/1/:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI doesn't include the core jQuery library. Add a reference to it before your jQuery UI reference.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

**EDIT:** It's worth noting that jsFiddle doesn't normally allow `<script>` tags in the HTML section. It definitely is not executing the CDN request. If you check the UI checkbox and run the fiddle, the button styles kick in...

Comment: Does not JSfiddle loads it automatically when set in the left menubar in "Frameworks and extensions" (just asking, not sure) ?

Comment: @vinaut It does, but the code the OP shows here does not include the jQuery reference. Basically, the jsFiddle doesn't seem to match what he's showing here...